# Hiker's Cabin Mystery | Pt. III

Tags: cipher

## [See Part I](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83495/hikers-cabin-mystery) | [See Part II](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83550/hikers-cabin-mystery-pt-ii) | [See Part IV](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83826/hiker-s-cabin-mystery-pt-iv)

Finally, you've gained access to his files... but the filenames are all encrypted! Oh, no!

[image: file directory]

You only have *one* chance to open the files! Which one should you open and why? (Hint: the file sizes have nothing to do with your answer!)

Comment: Do the specifics of the characters matter, or are they just symbols?  For example, does it matter that "è" is "è" and not "ð", or are they just arbitrarily chosen glyphs?  In the former case, you might want to put the textual version in the puzzle, too.

Comment: @Bobson That is a question that I will answer as a hint if enough time has passed...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is

> the result of doubling the character codes of all the characters in the following names: `Wrong`, `Incorrect`, `ThisIsIt`, `NotIt`, `IsntImportant`, `Nonexistent`, `Virus`.

So I think you want

> the third one.

Verification:

> put `''.join(chr(2*ord(c)) for c in 'Wrong Incorrect ThisIsIt NotIt IsntImportant Nonexistent Virus').replace('@',' ').replace('\x92','_').replace('\x9c','_')` into a Python 3 interpreter -- `@` is what a space turns into, and characters 92 and 9c are the ones that are being displayed as little boxes.

The main difficulty here was

> with *transcription* -- in several cases it wasn't clear whether we're looking at a capital or a lowercase letter, for instance. I actually noticed some time ago that a lot of the characters seem to have *even* character codes, but some of them appeared not to because I had guessed wrongly at what they were :-).

Comment: I thought it might be something like this, but I lost interest in trying to transcribe it to play around with it.  I can confirm that I get the same results doing this transform in C#, so I think this is the right answer.

Comment: I used Python to encode it!  :)

Comment: Well, of course :-).

Comment: Thanks for the nice juicy bounty :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan No problem!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

> According to my understanding filename need to start with certain characters only. It won't start with with special characters and spaces.
> So I will open the last file in the above image which is 83 MB.

Comment: Sorry, not correct, and you’re not really on the right track, .

Comment: Don’t assume that the filenames are that of a regular computer.