# Hiker’s Cabin Mystery | Pt. IV

Tags: logical-deduction

You’ve gotten into his computer and opened the correct file. Ready to read?

The file turned out to be an image... of a map.[image: map]

Where is our mystery hiker hiding out and how do you know?

Comment: Associated questions: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83495/hikers-cabin-mystery, https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83550/hikers-cabin-mystery-pt-ii, https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83628/hikers-cabin-mystery-pt-iii

Comment: @BenBarden Thank you, I was going to add that.

Comment: Is this intended to be standalone, or does it require context from the previous questions to solve?

Comment: @BenBarden It doesn’t require context, as some of them have not been answered correctly, yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's a bit simplistic, but might as well throw it out there.

> **Chad**.  The four countries pointed at are China, Hungary, Afghanistan, and Denmark... and barring something interesting in the bytecode of the image, or a way to take advantage of the length and direction of the arrows, there's not all that much information beyond that.

Comment: Absolutely right! I made it way too easy, I guess! I’ll mark it as accepted once you get a few more upvotes... :)

Comment: @INTERESTING,(+1) Why have you changed your name? :)

Comment: @Ak19 I am a TwoSet Violin fan (see my profile page)...

Comment: @INTERESTING #15NotesASecond lol

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Actually, 22!